# Insert item to an array of queue, C#

Tags: c#, queue

I need to insert a simple integer to the queue.

For some reason, it always collapsed on `null` reference. Do I need to init the queue? How to do this?

This my code.

```
Queue<int>[] OdafimColors = new Queue<int>[10];
OdafimColors[i].Enqueue(-1);
```

It is very simple, I can't realize why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize each element in your array:

```
for(int i = 0; i<OdafimColors.Lenght; i++)
      OdafimColors[i] = new Queue<int>();
```

Your definition doesn't allocate space for Queues. It allocates memory for the array and the elements are null until you initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want it to be an array.  That makes it an array of queues.

You probably want:

```
Queue<int> OdafimColors = new Queue<int>();
OdafimColors.Enqueue(-1);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Although his question states array of queue I feel as you do this wasn't his intentions. I up voted but it was down voted...